# horizontal scrollbar appearing, row having negative margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create layout like this link:http://deqsastudio.com/projects/screen.png

but the problem horizontal Scrollbar on the bottom not fixed which is keep moving.Like this:

Code:

```
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="header" class="row">
            <div id="logo" class="col-md-3">LOGO</div>
            <div id="nav" class="col-md-9">NAV</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Body -->
<div class="row nav-header">                
    <div class="container">
        <div id="switch-btn" class="col-md-3">SWITCH BUTTON</div>
        <div id="search" class="col-md-9">SEARCH BUTTON </div>
    </div>
</div>  


<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="popular-categories" class="col-md-3 "><p>POPULAR CATEGORIES</p></div>
        <div id="banner-slide" class="col-md-9"><p>BANNER SLIDE</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="term" class="col-md-3">TERM & CONDITIONS </div>
            <div id="copyright" class="col-md-3 pull-right">COPYRIGHT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7xQy/2/)

I hope my explanation explained well and understandable, Please help me on this :)

Comment: Please create the problem page on http://codepen.io/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us the real problem. Also you should paste the relevant code here in the question. Before you paste the code, try to take out the irrelevant part which don't cause the problem, and after taking out that code make sure the problem is still there.

Comment: actually i dont know how to put jsfiddle link. Here is the JSfiddle  link : http://jsfiddle.net/m7xQy/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see the css of the `.row` class, it has the css properties:

```
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

This is why the horizontal bar is being created, because the above properties utilize more space.

For this reason, we wrap the `.row` class within the `.container` which has the properties:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Thus, this equals out the space and you won't see the horizontal scrollbar anymore.

So, your HTML should look like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgQE9/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your body CSS

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m7xQy/10/

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to put an image off the page... Use these css codes:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#id-your-image {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; /* (or use -1 to put the img behind the layout */
    margin-left: 70%; /* (ajust the %) */
}
```

now in mobile, use inside the head tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```