# how to remove the bottom scroll?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

please help solve the problem.

there is a page [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11247/). If you compress it to the width(width < 420px), the bottom scrolling appears. and it should not be because it makes the bootstrap adaptive layout:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

body > .appointment_mobile > .container {
  padding: 0px 15px 0;
}
```

please help remove the lower scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when adding `padding:0` to your container. You'll break the Bootstrap logic and create that unnecessary margin.

This code is better if you just want to hide the top & bottom paddings.

```
body > .appointment_mobile > .container.menu_area {
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
.footer > .container.footer_area {
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
```

**TL;DR** you shouldn't do any left & right padding modification in the `container` class.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but actual problem is being caused by `bootstrap.css:1606`. which you can also override in your `css` (only for width < 480px)

```
.row {
   margin-right: -15px;
   margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: Please don't solve this problem by deleting the margin attributes on `row` and `overflow-x:hidden` on body could help this guy, but this is not a proper solution.

Comment: @hina10531 hence the first solution + added max width notice to second

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : 
You used to many .container class, when you use only one or two, it solves your problem.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
```

You can also see this answer:  [horizontal scrollbar appearing, row having negative margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029359/horizontal-scrollbar-appearing-row-having-negative-margin)

Here is a fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11250/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This question has a tag `bootstrap`. Don't say you don't know what framework he uses. Removing the `margin` attributes on `row` class could harm bootstrap's grid system.

Comment: Ok now i understand the negative note ( i read too fast, my bad ).
I was just saying it was a clue to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container > .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11248/**